# EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded to ios 9.2. Since then everytime I add a new person, I get following error

> Error getting changed object IDs since timestamp 474962070.619464 from
>   daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"

This error line appears for 4 times.

The new person does get added though.

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- I was related to calendar permissions. I believe EKCADErrorDomain is related to event kit.
- Also, ios 9.2 simulator takes some time to initialize all implicit data after simulator reset and boot. I had to run my app after few seconds of reboot to get it working properly.